# JavaDoc Parser for common javadocs?

Tags: java, parsing, javadoc, doclet

Is there something I can use to parse JavaDoc, such that I can operate on it through the standard Doclet interfaces at runtime? Essentially, the reverse operation of a [Doclet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/javadoc/doclet/com/sun/javadoc/package-summary.html).

I understand that it would be impossible to write a parser for every Javadoc (since this can be an arbitrary documentation format), but I'd be curious to know if there was something like that for the Standard Doclet.

Answer (score 1):

Doclet is a javadoc parser already. Think of the Doclet as a [SAX Parser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html)

Each call to your methods will be provided the exact same data that is given to a normal javadoc doclet.  Run your subclassed Doclet on the source code and it will present the documentation to you through the callback methods.